# How do you get rid of the blank page at the end of a document in Word 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I have a two-page document in Word 2019, and the second page is blank.

I clicked show/hide the paragraph marks. I then tried to highlight the single paragraph mark on the second page and to then hit backspace or delete but neither worked to get rid of it.

I need to solve this problem internally within the document so that it is consistently one-page when I send it out.  Adjusting the margins is no longer an option for me. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you share the document?

Comment: If you press Ctrl-End to go to the end of the document, do you position to the second page? If yes, press Backspace until you get rid of this page.

Comment: Delete the extra lines at the end of the document .   After the last visible character, press Delete a few times. I do this frequently.

Comment: See MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on this... http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BlankPage.htm

Comment: Here's how the problem was solved: In the View ribbon, I was working in Print Layout and I could see the extra page.  Then I shifted to Read Mode and the blank page was not displayed.  When I switched back to Print Layout after that, the blank page was gone.